# Ghost image of drag and drop takes the element and its sibling elements as well

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

When using drag and drop in chrome, I see that when I drag an element, the ghost image is not of this element but of the sibling elements as well (which are as well draggable).

How can I correct that? It gives the feeling you are dragging all the elements and that's not the case. The behavior when dropping the element is correct (only one element is dropped).

I've rapidly pasted the code in plunker and if you try to drag the elements there you'll see the problem
https://plnkr.co/edit/qm0XWu?p=preview

Any suggestion?

*some portion of the code from plunker, if you check this in plunker I've noticed that by eliminating the child elements the ghost image changes

```
  <div class="session" ng-reflect-bookmark_draggable="[object Object]" ng-reflect-id="session_4297" id="session_4297" ng-reflect-draggable="true" draggable="true">
    <session ng-reflect-index="2" ng-reflect-from="stored" ng-reflect-window="[object Object]">
      <div class="session_title">
        <span ng-reflect-class-name="folder type stored" class="folder type stored">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="folder expand">session_4297<span class="material-icons">list</span></span>
        <span class="folder edit"><span>edit</span><span class="material-icons">create</span></span>
        <span class="folder open"><span>open</span><span class="material-icons">tab</span></span>
        <span class="folder clear"><span>delete</span><span class="material-icons">clear</span></span>
      </div>
```

Comment: I can't drag and drop anything in plunkr, please check. There is no js in the js file

Comment: There's no js, correct, and you don't have to drag and drop, you have to drag and you will see how the ghost image doesn't correspond to the element only, but to a lot of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if I put all child elements with `display: none`, then the drag effect is the one one would expect. When the children have a normal `display` property (but in this case `opacity:0`), then the ghost image takes a random? number of sibling elements.

By modifying this I have solved the issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did to fix the issue? I'm having the same problem (in Chrome, works fine in IE).

Comment: I don't precisely remember it right now, but quick&dirty, if in the plunker you go to the `style.css`, line 65, and add there a `display:none`, then all the child elements are not displayed instead of not visible, and that makes the trick

Answer (score 1):

make sure the dragging element has the opacity of 0.5 or < 1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow user17048179. This is an answer; and as far as I can tell a good addition to the other one ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049295/7733418 ). But you could probably improve it an increase the chance for upvotes by using this helpful info [answer]. You might also want to take the [tour]. Have fun.